# How to set default values/placeholders for depended select lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder, selectlist

I have four depended select lists and I want to give all the select lists a default value/placeholder like this: `select ...`. The problem is that when I try to do it like this: `<option value=""> Select ... </option>` it doesn't work. Because when I change the first select list the other select lists gets automically changed because of the dependency.

This is how I'm filling my depended select lists:

```
    $("#slctTable").change(function()
    {
        $.getJSON("dropdown_code/get_fields.php?table=" + $(this).val(), success = function(data)
        {
                optionsFields= "";
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                optionsFields += "<option value='" + data[i]['field_name'] + "'>" + data[i]['field_alias'] + "</option>";
            }
        $("#slctField").html("");
        $("#slctField").append(optionsFields);
        $("#slctField").change();
        })
    });   
    });
```

Whit this function I'm putting the optionsFields into an array:

```
function allValues(el) {
  var arr = $('option', el).map(function(i, v) {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `optionsFields= "";` use  `optionsFields= "<option value='0'> Select... </option>"`. it's not working because you're probably setting your default value in HTML and overwriting it in your change function.

Comment: You'r solution worked, but because I work with an array and the `value=' '` I get a query error because it's doing `' ', columnName1, columnName2`. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: if I understand what you're saying...you just need to ignore index 0 (zero) of the select option array. You do not have to use it...it's just a default value...not usefull for the application...right?

Comment: Yeah that's right. I updated my code to show you the function I made to put the optionsFields into an array.

Comment: so...everything is working now or do you need any help? To fix it you just need to execute your change function only when the selectedIndex is different from zero.

Comment: The function creats an array. But the array is filled like this now: `'0' , columnName1, columnName2` but it needs to be like this: `columName1, columnName2` or else the query will give an error.

Comment: define a default value for the default option ("", 0, whatever) and in your function just `if this.value != defaultValue return this.value;`

Comment: I use that function for different arrays, so I can't give it one default value. Isn't there a way to say something like: If the first value of the array is `'0',` than don't return the array or remove the `'0',` from the array?

Comment: i'm not used to use .map function...but, I think the parameters you're using, give it to you this information. try `$('option', el).map(function(index){if (index !=0) return this.value});`

Comment: Yeah that worked! I only needed to add the `.get();` at the end. Thanks a lot fo the help!

Answer (score 0):

It will be great if you can share the exact fiddle, but looking onto your javascript, I can see one issue.

Instead of calling:

```
 $("#slctTable").change();
```

I think you should call

```
 $("#slctTable").trigger("change");
```

to trigger the change event

Also, its better to have a default string which has the value

```
<option value="">Select...</option>
```

Further to this, it will be great if you can create a generic function which can create option strings from the provided array and also can append default option as well in that string. In that case, it will reduce the chances of fault, like the way we have here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips I will look into them but @Elmer Dantas answer worked.

Comment: Great. let me know if you face any other issue.